# F8 or "Run Selection" not working in VS Code while trying to run powershell commands in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-5.0

I am using VS Code and i have my powershell terminal in VS Code as well as Powershell ISE. I have my own personal script file in the form of .ps1 which has some list of commands. When i select a command in the file and right click and choose "Run Selection" , that doesn't get reflected in the Powershell Terminal in VS code. I even tried Function + F8 key of the laptop, still the same. Any idea what do i need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and I came into the solution. Just install the powershell extension for VS code and you'll see the Run Selection/F8 work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, F8 stopped running selected script suddenly. Had to reinstall the PowerShell extension for VScode and it fixed it.

Check key bindings as well by hitting Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S and search "Run Selection". This should be a sub function of the PowerShell extension.